# 'IN' gives empty result - c# and cosmos

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to query the cosmos and the query works. The query looks like

```
'Select * from c where c.id IN ('123', '456')'.
```

Now in my c# code, I get empty result. The c# code looks like :

```
public void GetValue(IEnumerable<string> ids, string s)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new();
            _ = sb.Append("SELECT t.id FROM t ")
                .Append("WHERE t.id IN (@items) ")
                .Append("AND t.state != @state");

            var queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition(sb.ToString())
                .WithParameter("@items", ids)
                .WithParameter("@state", s);

           var results = GetQueryResults<TableName>(queryDefinition); // Get Empty Result
          // Some logic based on results
        }

// GetQueryResults query the container and gets the result for the tableName.
```

SO, I was able to conclude that the 'IN' query syntax is incorrect. Can anyone help me out.

Comment: How are you consuming the query? Can you share what `GetQueryResults` does?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta GetQueryResults just query the container. It works for all of my other queries.

Comment: the text you shows does not include 'state' but the code does

Comment: You cannot parameterize the list the IN condition.

Comment: Can you please share the code of GetQueryResults? I understand it works, but in order to help you, having that piece of information would be helpful. If you don't want to share, at least check if the code is draining the full query and not reading the first page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.feediterator-1?view=azure-dotnet#examples

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta Yes, it is draining the full query. As Palle mentioned, I cannot parameterize the list, so I am thinking how to do that ? That example doesn't help much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```cs
.Append("WHERE t.id IN (@items) ")
```

The list cannot be parameterized. One possiblity is to add the list items as separate parameters. There is an example of that [here](https://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2016/01/parameterize-sql-where-in-clause-c/).

**EDIT**
I found the solution [here](https://eysermans.com/post/things-i-wish-knew-before-i-got-started-with-cosmos-db)

```cs
var querySpec = new SqlQuerySpec {
    QueryText = "SELECT t.Id FROM t WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(@Ids, t.Id)",
    Parameters = new SqlParameterCollection {
        new SqlParameter { 
            Name = "@Ids",
            Value = ids
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not using sqlcommand. How to add it then ?

Comment: Can I do it without SqlCommand ?

Comment: Oh, it was a little late when I answered, like gremlins I shouldn't be kept up after midnight. I didn't notice the cosmos tag. You should be able to do something similar, I'll see if I can find the time to extend my answer.